# Can a business itself that rent digital content from other content provider stream the content freely

Tags: contract-law, internet

My question is if a business (its staff) that purchased TVOD (pay-per-view) streaming content can freely stream the content for themselves usually?  Is there a norm or does that strictly depend on the contract signed with the purchased content.

Comment: What does the contract say?

Answer (score 1):

It strictly depends on the contract/license.